# udisks excluding system global mount options when mounting

Tags: mount, partition, ext4, fstab, udisks

I have updated my embedded linux, but the `udisksctl` does not work as expected anymore. If I try to mount a ext4 formatted flash drive I get the following error:

```
root@system:~# udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1
Error mounting /dev/sda1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.OptionNotPermitted: Mount option `errors=remount-ro' is not allowed
```

I do not know why and how the option `errors=remount-ro` is being forced!

If I try to mount with `mount` command it works just fine:

```
root@system:~# mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/mydrive
```

My question is, where does `udisksctl` brings that remount-ro into the play and how can I avoid or exclude that option?

I have already looked in `fstab` and found nothing interesting in there. Where are these options being read by udisks ?

Comment: What is your `udisks` version? Also, post the content of `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` if such a file exists on your system.

Comment: @don_crissti It is v2.9.0 and that file does not exist

Answer (score 1):

UDisks carries a set of **builtin** allowed mount options for well known filesystem types and related set of default options that are always passed to the mount command. In particular, regarding the ext4 filesystem :

```
ext4_defaults=errors=remount-ro
ext4_allow=errors=remount-ro
```

This explains why `udisksctl mount` would fail in case the `remount-ro` option is specified at a higher overriding level.

**The first level of overriding is offered by some udisks configuration file : mount_options.conf**

Its default location is `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf`**

Look for lines starting with `ext4_defaults`

But I would find highly surprising that options set in this specific udisks file conflict with `udisks` builtin rules. So… the magic is likely to com from… the second and highest level of overrides : `udev`.

**udev rules can also override respective keys from both the config file level and the base builtin mount options.**

Common locations for the ruleset are `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and `/lib/udev/rules.d` so just parse these directories for some rule specifically overriding mount options. Since this rule should run last, the associated filename is likely to be 99- prefixed.

Comment: Thanks I gotta try that and report back :)